# Are security.ubuntu.com updates eventually merged into normal updates?

Tags: official-repositories

Upon my observation, seems new packages will first appear in security.ubuntu.com, but if you upgrade later, they will appear in XX.archive.ubuntu.com (depends on your config),

Was that true ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Short answer: no. Security updates never become "recommended" updates.

- *security.ubuntu.com* is the same as *archive.ubuntu.com* (try pinging both and checking the IP they resolve to)

  - Compare the contents of [*security*](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/), and [*archive*](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/)
- What matters for critical security updates is the `-security` repository, which is carried by *all* mirrors (e.g. `precise-security`)

  - The only reason I can think of that Ubuntu keeps using *security.ubuntu.com* instead of your local mirror is to minimize the risk of any problems if that mirror does not regularly sync to the master repository
  - If your mirror is updated regularly, you can just add/edit a line such as:

  ```
  deb http://xx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
  ```

> From the [official repository description](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu):
>
> - "Important Security Updates (lucid-security)". Patches for security vulnerabilities in Ubuntu packages. They are managed by the Ubuntu Security Team and are designed to change the behavior of the package as little as possible -- in fact, the minimum required to resolve the security problem. As a result, they tend to be very low-risk to apply and all users are urged to apply security updates.
> - "Recommended Updates (lucid-updates)". Updates for serious bugs in Ubuntu packaging that do not affect the security of the system.

Comment: When I ping *security.ubuntu.com* it resolves to keeton.canonical.com (91.189.88.161). When I ping *archive.ubuntu.com* it resolves to steelix.canonical.com (91.189.88.152).

Comment: There is a loss of security in `UBUNTU.com` install, download, apt, etc. ecossystem by "no DNSSEC"?  Compare with [Debian.org](http://debian.org) (see `whois debian.org | grep -i sec`) that is signed.

Comment: @EliahKagan The IP addresses pointed by them can vary at times, if you ping them many times.

Answer (score 6):

Security updates can and do become recommended updates.

From the [Ubuntu Security Team FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/FAQ):

> While packages are copied from security to updates frequently, it is recommended that systems always have the security pocket enabled, and use security.ubuntu.com for this pocket.