# What is the difference between security.ubuntu.com and archive.ubuntu.com?

Tags: security, apt-mirror

The various releases have a `-security` channel in `archive.ubuntu.com`. How does that channel differ from the `security.ubuntu.com`? If I have to set up a local mirror, how does `security.ubuntu.com` come into the picture? I am using `apt-mirror` for mirroring.

Comment: this should answer it http://askubuntu.com/a/185444/15811 (?)

Comment: @Rinzwind in effect I can skip the `security.ubuntu.com` lines if I do update my mirror regularly?

Comment: I would says yes to that :=)

Comment: May http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/ help you?

Comment: @Pandya I doubt it. It's a list of security notices (interesting, certainly), but doesn't explain how security.ubuntu differs from archive.ubuntu. I do know that security.ubuntu.com redirects to that page.