# What is the difference between http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security and http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security

Tags: package-management, updates, security

I am trying to understand how security updates work for the ubuntu package mirror. I see [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/FAQ) that the recommendation is to set up security.ubuntu.com as the apt source for the security pocket, and to set archive.ubuntu.com as the apt source for all other pockets. I assume that these correspond to the `bionic-security` dist and `bionic`, `bionic-updates`, `bionic-backports`, and `bionic-proposed` apt sources present in my apt config file. Further, it looks like the config file correspondes to these dists directories seen [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/)
However, it looks like archive.ubuntu.com has the `bionic-security` dist present as well. How is this different than the dist of the same name present on security.ubuntu.com? As far as I can tell these are updated at the same cadence. Are these effectively the same? If so, why is it recommended to use security.ubuntu.com for the `-security` source?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are security.ubuntu.com updates eventually merged into normal updates?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185317/are-security-ubuntu-com-updates-eventually-merged-into-normal-updates) (via [What is the difference between security.ubuntu.com and archive.ubuntu.com?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504545/what-is-the-difference-between-security-ubuntu-com-and-archive-ubuntu-com))