# What is CVE-2015-1793? Does it affect me?

Tags: security, bug-reporting, openssl

Apparently a new bug has been discovered in OpenSSL, it is being called as [**Alternative chains certificate forgery (CVE-2015-1793)**](https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv_20150709.txt).

[Canonical already declared](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2015/CVE-2015-1793.html) the versions of `openssl` that are not affected with currently supported releases.

I am using version `1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.8` of `openssl` (can be found with `apt-cache policy openssl`) in `14.04` but accoding to Canonical the not-affected version for `14.04` is `1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.15`. But there is no such version available in the repository (Why not yet?).

My questions are :

- Does that mean i am vulnerable to CVE-2015-1793 ?
- And obviously what exactly is CVE-2015-1793 ? How can it affect me ?

Comment: The version number in 14.04 appears to be [1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.15](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/openssl). You may want to check where 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.8 comes from.

Comment: @mikewhatever Trusty comes with [1.0.1f-1ubuntu2](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/1.0.1f-1ubuntu2)..`1.0.1f-1ubuntu8` comes from the `main` repo..apparently i was using the wrong mirror..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Please note:

This latest vulnerability (CVE-2015-1793) was introduced in a recent update to OpenSSL package (as maintained by OpenSSL.org).

OpenSSL's latest advisory: https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv_20150709.txt

**This should not affect a *standard* Ubuntu install.**

---

from: [ComputerWorld >> OpenSSL fixes serious flaw (Jul 9, 2015)](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2946042/security/openssl-fixes-serious-flaw-that-could-enable-maninthemiddle-attacks.html)

"*.. the OpenSSL packages distributed with some Linux distributions -- including Red Hat, Debian and Ubuntu -- **are not affected**. That's because Linux distributions typically backport security fixes into their packages instead of completely updating them to new versions.*".

---

**Note:** *You may still be affected, if you are using the OpenSSL package (or source) directly from OpenSSL.org.*

Comment: Hmmm. Seems I misread the Ubuntu CVE Tracker. When I read `1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.15` is not affected, I thought it implied older versions were.

Answer (score 2):

No, you are not vulnerable to CVE-2015-1793, but you are likely vulnerable to several other bugs. The latest version from the Ubuntu Security Team version is in the [`trusty-updates`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/openssl) and [`trusty-security`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/openssl) repositories as expected (see the [Security Team FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/FAQ#Repositories)) and the CVE tracker says that it **isn't** affected. If you can't see this version yet, check:

- if you have enabled `trusty-security` and `trusty-updates` repositories
- if your mirror (if not an official one) has fallen behind in syncing (check [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors))
- if you have the `security.ubuntu.com` repository enabled (it's enabled by default)

The last point is important. Since [`security.ubuntu.com` is an alias for the main repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185317/are-security-ubuntu-com-updates-eventually-merged-into-normal-updates), and it is enabled by default for the `-security` channel, you should **always** have access to any security fixes published by Ubuntu. For example:

```
$ apt-cache policy openssl      
openssl:
  Installed: 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.11
  Candidate: 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.15
  Version table:
     1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.15 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.11 0
        500 http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.0.1f-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Apparently i was using the lazy mirror..

Comment: muru, do you know what this is? what are the security concerns ? or do you want me to ask a new question ?

Comment: @heemayl I'm looking around myself to understand what exactly happens. At the moment, everybody seems to be using the same vague description. Though you could ask on [security.se] about how it actually works.

Comment: Seems [the question has been asked already](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/93524)..gonna follow that..also if you found anything interesting lem me know or add to the answer..

Comment: @heemayl Seems I was wrong. See david6's answer.

Comment: @heemayl certainly.